# Rails - Convert hours and minutes to seconds then assign value to key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to combine both values `:hours` and `:minutes` and convert them to `to_i` in seconds. Next is to assign this value (which should be in seconds) to the `:time_duration` which is a column in the `cars` db before it creates a new `service`. The `:time_duration` is in a `hidden_field` because there's no reason to render this data in the view.

> **views**

This is my `_car_fields.html.erb` which is a nested partial inside a view template called, `_form.html.erb` .

**_car_fields.html.erb**

```
<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :name %><br>
        <%= f.label :hours %>
        <%= f.select :hours, '0'..'8' %>
        <%= f.label :minutes %>
        <%= f.select :minutes, options_for_select( (0..45).step(15), selected: f.object.minutes )%><br>
        <%= f.label :price %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :price, :value => (number_with_precision(f.object.price, :precision => 2) || 0) %> <br>
        <%= f.label :details %><br>
        <%= f.text_area :details %></div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove Car", f, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :time_duration, value: %>
  <br>
    <hr>
</div>
```

---

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @service do |f| %>
  <div class="field">

    <%= f.label "Select service category" %>
    <br>

    <%= collection_select(:service, :service_menu_id, ServiceMenu.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => true }) %>

    <%= f.fields_for :cars do |task| %>
      <%= render 'car_fields', :f => task %>
    <% end %>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <%= link_to_add_association 'Add New Car', f, :cars, class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  </div><br>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

> **controller**

**services_controller**

```
def new
    @service = current_tech.services.build
  end

  def create
    @service = current_tech.services.build(service_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @service.save
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Service was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @service }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @service.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def service_params
      params.require(:service).permit(:name, :service_menu_id, cars_attributes: [:tech_id, :name, :hours, :minutes, :price, :details, :_destroy])
    end
```

---

> **models**

**service.rb**

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base  
    belongs_to :tech
    belongs_to :service_menu
    has_many :cars, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :cars, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**car.rb**

```
class Car< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :tech
  has_many :appointments 
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can remove the hidden `time_duration` field from the form, since it is not needed.

Then, you'll create a `before_save` method for your car model:

**car.rb**

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service
  belongs_to :tech
  has_many :appointments 

  before_save :generate_time_duration

  def generate_time_duration
    self[:time_duration] = hours.hours.to_i + minutes.minutes.to_i
  end
end
```

**What this does:** Before the car object is saved, it will run the `generate_time_duration` method. What this method does is it simply sums the `hours.to_i` and `minutes.to_i` and assigns it to the car's `time_duration` attribute.

---

**Update old DB records**

Since you're adding this functionality in your application AFTER records have already been created, here is a quick way to update all of your current records:

1. In your command line, open a rails console by running the command `rails c` (or `rails console`)
2. In the console, run this command: `Car.all.each { |c| c.save! }`

This is a quick, one-time fix that will loop through all Car records, save them, and subsequently update their `time_duration` fields.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You posted: `self[:time_duration] = hours.to_i + minutes.to_i`. This did not convert correctly. I corrected this by doing: `self[:time_duration] = hours.hour.to_i + minutes.minute.to_i` and it worked. :)

Comment: Ahh, you're right, I overlooked that. Glad it helped! I'll update the answer

Comment: Is there a way I can mass populate the `time_duration` column with the values already stored in the `minutes` and `hours` column? There's a lot of house keeping I may have to do. Was hoping a way to convert the data already in the `hours` and `minutes` column, convert them to seconds then mass populate the `time_duration` column.

Comment: I'll add a solution for you to the answer